# Debugging Background Task Event cancellation in Win RT (c#)

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I'm working on a Win Phone 8.1 App that uses the background audio player, but I'm having trouble, particularly when it comes to the cancellation event. I want to debug it myself to learn but I can't seem to find a way to manually cancel the background task other than to pause and wait 5 minutes while the app is suspended, something impossible while debugging.

Is there a way to do so cleanly (ie. Not artificially increasing memory usage)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There come two ways to my mind, both quite easy to do:

- invoke [BackgroundMediaPlayer.Shutdown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.media.playback.backgroundmediaplayer.shutdown.aspx) from your code
- while debugging, hit <kbd>Start</kbd>, find *Music* app, open, start playing an audio file - hence there can be only one Instance of MediaPlayer, yours will be cancelled.